# Testing domains on NGINX before DNS switch

Tags: nginx, dns

I am looking for some assistance in a way to configure my .conf file for nginx to point to a domain for testing before switching the actual DNS.

I have the following:

1. Maindomain.com running a WordPress install
2. comingsoon.com running a basic PHP site in the directory as listed below.

I would like to access comingsoon.com contents on a url somthing like maindomain.com/comingsoon

I feel I am on the right track but may be missing something as I am getting a 404.

Here is my conf file:

```
server {
  server_name maindomain.com;
  root /var/www/maindomain.com/public/;
  listen 8080;
  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
  }                                      

  location /comingsoon { 
    root /var/www/comingsoon.com/public/;      
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
  }                                        

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/dev/shm/php-fpm-www.sock;
  }                                        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always set manually www.comingsoon.com to point to the nginx server through adding a record in your hosts file. Besides that, it is not obvious why you gey 404. First guess is:

```
location /comingsoon { 
    root /var/www/comingsoon.com/public/;
}
```

This mean that the **'index index.html index.htm index.php'** files will be searched into directory **/var/www/comingsoon.com/public/comingsoon/**. Is this the real dir?

EDIT: To avoid adding the location to the root dir, use alias:

```
location /comingsoon { 
    alias /var/www/comingsoon.com/public/;
}
```

This way the file /commingsoon/index.html will be served at /var/www/comingsoon.com/public/index.html.
More info on aliases - here: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#alias

Comment: Thank you for the reply Tisho.  The directory is actually /var/www/comingsoon.com/public/ where the files live.